# How to import FooterCaption from 'react-images'?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use the library 'react-images' in my reactjs project.  I am receiving the error "Unexpected token" in the react-images\src\components\Footer.js file.  Also, on the same line i have the error "'import ... =' can only be used in a .ts file.".

```
import type { PropsWithStyles, ViewType } from '../types';
```

Also, I am receiving the error "'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file." in many of the component files in 'react-images' library.  Why is this?  Thanks.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import Carousel, { Modal, ModalGateway, FooterCaption } from 'react-images';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand how this library is designed. If you look at the documentation, `FooterCaption` is listed under [Component API](http://jossmac.github.io/react-images/#/components). That means `FooterCaption` is part of the API for the `Carousel` component meaning that this is designed with the *Slots Pattern*.

If you look at the example code above it, it shows you how this works.

```
<Carousel components={{ Header: CustomHeader }} />
```

The `Carousel` component has a prop called `components` which takes an object. This object is expected to have keys that are one of the various replaceable components listed under **Component API**. The value is expected to be a something that React can render; typically a component. This example is replacing the `Header` with a custom header component called `CustomHeader`.

If you don't override the component, then `Carousel` will render something by default as described in the documentation for each component under **Component API**.

If you would like to override the default `FooterCaption`, then you will do something like this:

```
<Carousel components={{ FooterCaption: MyCustomFooterCaption }} />
```

Where `MyCustomFooterCaption` is a component you've defined elsewhere. The props it will receive from the `Carousel` component can be found in the [source code](https://github.com/jossmac/react-images/blob/37332404a97404e65228e97432bf190ee9c7a525/src/components/Footer.js#L86).

To summarize:

- You don't need to import `FooterCaption`.
- If you plan on overriding the default `FooterCaption`, then create your own component and pass it in as shown in example.

The same goes for everything listed under **Component API**.

Comment: Yes, it looks like i was misinterpreting the documentation.  It looks to be working now.  Thank you.